# Life time $t_+(0)=\infty$ for system of ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $K\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$. Consider the system of ordinary differential equations
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \partial_t f(t,u)&=R(f(t,u))\\
> f(0,u)&=u
> \end{align}
> $$
> where $R:K^d\rightarrow K^d$ is a locally Lipschitz continuous function. Then the following holds:
>
> For every $u\in K^d$, there exists a life time $t_+(u)\in(0,\infty]$ such that there exists a unique solution $f(\cdot, u):[0,t_+(u))\rightarrow K^d$ of the ODE.

Now the author states, that it is easily checked, that $t_+(0)=\infty$.

Isn't that, by just picking $f(\cdot,0)= 0$ or do I overlook something, here?

**EDIT:** As Lutz Lehmann has pointed out, this is not true in general.

Consider $u=0\in\mathbb{R}$ and the locally Lipschitz continuous function $R(y):=1+y^2$. Then the ODE is solved by $f(t,0):=\tan(t)$, since

$$\partial_t f(t,0)=\partial_t \tan(t)=1+\tan^2(t)=R(\tan(t))=R(f(t,0))$$
and
$$f(0,0)=\tan(0)=0$$

However, the life time is in this case $t_+(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and not equal to $\infty$.

Comment: No, that is wrong without any other conditions on $R$. Just take $d=1$ and $R(y)=1+y^2$ to get very finite values for $t_+$.

Comment: If for example your last line would read $R(0)=0$, then the claim $t_+(0)=\infty$ is trivially true, as the zero solution would be defined on all of $\Bbb R$ and be unique.

Comment: Actually, I only need it for the Riccati equations, see Lemma 2.3 in this arxiv file: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.4003.pdf However, I still don't know yet, how I could find $t_+(0)=\infty$. Could you give a further hint?

Comment: Those equations have $R(0)=0$, as $R(y)=α[y,y]+β[y]$, with $α$ bi-linear and $β$ linear, both vector valued.

Comment: Ok, in the case of the Riccati equations $(\Phi(\cdot,0),\Psi(\cdot,0))=0$ solves the equation and is defined on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: However, the statement in the citation is true, right?

Comment: Yes, that is a typical statement about the maximal solution or maximal domain of a solution.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for all your help and your fast replies. I cannot thank you enough.  Wishing you a great time!